# WPF: Is there something like Canvas.IsVisible(point)?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there something like `Canvas.IsVisible(point)` ?

I have a `Canvas` inside a `ScrollViewer`. Inside the canvas I have a custom control that should be always in the visible part of the Canvas.

[image]

Is there a way to identify the Canvas *visible* rectangle or point?

Comment: `BringIntoView` won't work for you? You can determine when any parent controls update their layout and perform this action appropriately.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: actually I tested and `BringIntoView()` moves the canvas to the Control. I need to move the control whitin the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension method that checks whether an element is fully visible inside a container:

```
public static bool IsUserVisible(this FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;

    var bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.Contains(bounds);
}
```

In your case you can try using it something like this:

```
myUserControl.IsUserVisible(scrollViewerWithMyCanvas);
```

Comment: see also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/01/18/elements-visibility-inside-scrollviewer.aspx

Comment: Can `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` be `NaN`? How does this handle such, if so?

Comment: @Robert - Thank you for the link. It might be useful.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - It cannot be NaN if the element passed the Arrange stage.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - 'Actual' values will never be NaN.  Height and Width may be if you haven't set them but ActualHeight and ActualWidth will always be real numbers (defaulting to 0 if they haven't been measured yet)

Comment: Is there a way to find also the relative visible rectangle coordinates? (the blue rectangle location inside the red one)?

Comment: because I see you do `var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0`, shouldn't you do  `var rect = new Rect(visibleRectangleLocation.X, visibleRectangleLocation.Y` instead?

Comment: @serhio - No, `new Rect(0.0, 0.0...` is OK, because `bounds` coordinates are relative to the `container` coordinates.

Comment: @Pavlo: so what? bounds (green) is relative to container (red) coordinates. So do rect (blue) coordinates. But the blue rectangle have no 0,0 location in the (red) container. I need to calculate the blue rectangle location...

Comment: I tested your method, it does not work... return always true when the object is visible (in or not in the view)...

Comment: @serhio - when you do `greenRectangle.IsUserVisible(blueRectangle)`, the method returns whether `greenRectangle` is fully visible inside `blueRectangle`. And it doesn't matter what coordinates `blueRectangle` has. What matters is the relative position of `greenRectangle` inside `blueRectangle`.

Comment: @serhio -  You need to pass the `ScrollViewer` to this method instead of `Canvas` to make it work because you are trying to determine whether a control is visible inside a `ScrollViewer` not a `Canvas`. Sorry for misleading example in my post.

Comment: @Pavlo. OK, works better with the scrollview. But however, as I need to adjust the green rectangle position, I need to know the blue coordinates.

Comment: @serhio - To get coordinates of an element relative to another element use this: `element.TransformToAncestor(parentElement).Transform(new Point(0, 0))`

Comment: @Pavlo: I saw it from your example. However the scrollviewer is special. It is docked in the parent Canvas, but however 0,0 coordinate is always the upper left *visible* point.

Answer (score -3):

You can use ZOrder property of canvas and always put yours control on the top of canvas

Comment: That doesn't at all address this scrollviewer issue